Issue with Procedure or function has too many arguments specified
I'm facing a problem where I was prompted that I'm passing too many parameters even though I defined it to both stored proc (SQL Server) and VB.NET:
ERROR:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Procedure or function pro_SearchBySCQTY has too many arguments specified.'

UPDATED ERROR

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Procedure or function 'pro_SearchInvBySCwithQTY' expects parameter '@Qty', which was not supplied.'

These is my current code:
VB.NET
 If rsfind.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            rsfind.Close()
        End If
        rsfind.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
        rsfind.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic
        rsfind.LockType = ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic
        Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
        With cmd
            .ActiveConnection = [redacted]
            .CommandText = "pro_SearchInvBySCwithQTY"
            .CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc

            For i = cmd.Parameters.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                cmd.Parameters.Delete(i)
            Next i

            .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@SearchTerm", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 50, Trim(ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(0).Text)))
            .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@QTY", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(3).Text))
            rsfind.Open(.Execute)
        End With

SQL Server stored procedure
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pro_SearchInvBySCwithQTY] @SearchTerm NVARCHAR(MAX), @QTY INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT StockCode, Description, Supplier, AlternateKey1, AlternateKey2, Classification, QtyOnHand, DateLastStockMove, SafetyStockQty, ReOrderQty, SellingPrice, StockOnHold, StockUom, DefaultBin
    FROM vw_InventorySearchBySC
    WHERE StockCode = @SearchTerm AND QtyOnHand = @QTY
    order by DateLastStockMove DESC; 
END;



Could it be that you have multiple procedures "pro_SearchBySCQTY" exist under different schemas? Silly question: did you actually run the "ALTER PROCEDURE" code after you have made the changes?

not really, I also tried to create another stored proc, same problem

Silly question: did you actually run the "ALTER PROCEDURE" code after you have made the changes?

No. Just to show my stored proc.

How are you making changes to stored procedure? Is it in SSMS? Visual Studio? Where did you get code for it?

the codes of stored proc are inside ssms.

And you run the code after you have added a second parameter?

From SSMS can you run your stored procedure e.g. EXEC [dbo].[pro_SearchBySCQTY] 'enter your search term', 2? Do you get any errors?

As Alex mentioned, you can run that query to SSMS to make sure, the code is proper.
But if we simply state this error then, "You are passing more parameters than it was specified in the stored procedure".

Seems like you're reusing the cmd object between calls, so each time you invoke this block of code another two parameters get added to its ParameterCollection.

querying it to sql works. but in vb net, not

is it advisable to call cmd within each block scope?

i'll revise it if that's the case because I defined cmd in the namespace scope.

Generally speaking Connections and Commands should be created, used, and disposed of immediately. Attempting to reuse them leads to difficulties such as the one you're currently facing.

I revised it and now I got this error this time:

'Procedure or function 'pro_SearchInvBySCwithQTY' expects parameter '@Qty', which was not supplied.'

fyi I included the qty which is here
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@SearchTerm", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 50, Trim(ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(0).Text)))
.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@QTY", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(3).Text))
andn I defined it in stored proc based on this post

Please Edit your question to show the current version of the code, blocks of code should not be pasted into comments. People reading this question will only see the original version that you posted and comments destroy formatting (as you've noticed).

And questions are not debugging sessions, you can't keep changing the question are asking.

When you debug does the selected value for quantity contain a value?


Why are you deleting parameters for a Command that you just declared as New? 2. Are you sure you aren't getting a Nothing or String.Empty value for ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(3).Text? 3. Turn Option Strict On, so ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(3).Text fails because you aren't converting it to the Integer the parameter expects.

